# Handle with dynamically made elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button

Is there a way to handle elements made dynamically on loading the page?

for example, I have a code below.

```
function makeAFrame(index)
{
    var padding=document.createElement('p');
    var frameDiv=document.createElement('div');
    frameDiv.id="frame";
    frameDiv.className="frame";

    var placeButton=document.createElement('input');
    placeButton.id="bButton"+index;
    placeButton.className="bButton";
    placeButton.value="aaa";
    placeButton.type="button";

    var buyButton=document.createElement('input');
    buyButton.id="aButton"+index;
    buyButton.className="aButton";
    buyButton.value="Buy It Now";
    buyButton.type="button";

    var table=document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute('cellpadding','3');
    table.setAttribute('width','100%');

    var col1=["a", "b", "c","d","e:", "f"];

    var row;
    var text;
    var cell;
    var i=0;

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        row = table.insertRow(i);

        text = document.createTextNode(col1[i]);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.setAttribute('align','right');
        cell.setAttribute('width','30%');
        cell.appendChild(text);

        text = document.createTextNode(hey[index][i]);
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.setAttribute('align','left');
        cell.appendChild(text);
    }

    for(i=6;i<8;i++)
    {
        row = table.insertRow(i);

        text = document.createTextNode("");
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.setAttribute('align','right');
        cell.setAttribute('width','30%');
        cell.appendChild(text);

        if(i==7)
        {
            cell = row.insertCell(1);
            cell.setAttribute('align','left');
            cell.appendChild(placeButton);
            cell.appendChild(buyButton);
            break;
        }
        else if(i==6)
        text = document.createTextNode(remaining);
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.setAttribute('align','left');
        cell.appendChild(text);
    }

    var body=document.getElementById('body');
    frameDiv.appendChild(table);
     body.appendChild(frameDiv);
     body.appendChild(padding);
}
```

Once the function has been run which means after all elements are shown in the page. What I would like to do is when I click a 'aButton0'(aButton+index) a input box shows up. I make all button codes with index so they are accessible but I have no idea how to access after they are shown in the page.

Comment: any js fiddle with code

Comment: What is array `hey` in your code? Can you provide a *working example* so we don't have to tap in the mist? Edit this one: http://jsbin.com/toyig/1/edit

Comment: I edited the code there. The array doesn't matter. You can replace it with any string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just add an onclick handler to your button when you create it, just add

```
  placeButton.setAttribute("onclick", "showPopUp();");
```

Then you can react to your specific button within in the showPopUp function.

Comment: I just tried but your statement runs every time the element creates. I want to handle them after they have created.

Comment: when exactly do you want to add the handler then and whats the problem then?

Comment: When the page loads, it will make some tables and buttons in every table. when the all components are shown in the page, i want to click a button on the page and want it to show up a input box so i can type.

Comment: then you should use window.onload = whenPageLoaded; this adds an event handler to the DOM which fires when your page is loaded. in your whenPageLoaded function you create your button which should open the input box, you may have a look at window.prompt() function for the input box

Comment: sorry for my poor English. I think you got my comment wrong. my all elements are shown well with my code but i want to handle them AFTER they are created.

Comment: im sorry i dont know what you actually want to archieve, can you be more specific?

Comment: You see the function above? The function, makeAFrame() is called when the page is loaded which means after running all codes in the function, I can get some tables and buttons from the code. <- This is what I've done so far. Now I want to press a button that has been just created and also want it to show me a input box when I click it.

Comment: therefor you have to add an onclick handler like i posted in my answer, are you sure you didnt miss the quotation marks ? Thats what might have happend as you said the statement runs on creation. The onclick function should run when the button is actually clicked! I think this should work. If you still have problems can you embed all neccessary stuff in an JSFiddle please ?

Comment: ok found it : the handler seems not to get attached with .onclick its :  placeButton.setAttribute("onclick", "showPopUp();");